# jersey @GET collection and @GET collection filtered by @QueryParam

Tags: java, rest, jersey, uri

In my app users can register, that users can post workouts and comments on workouts.

I design following resources and URIs:

```
USERS
/users
/users/{id}

WORKOUTS
/workouts
/workouts/{id}

COMMENTS
/workouts{id}/comments
/workouts{id}/comments/{id}
```

Since /workouts URI returns timeline, I tried to map user's workouts like /workouts?user=userId

I don´t know how distinguish between get all collection and get collection filtered by @QueryParam, because:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Practicas getPracticas() {
    List<Practica> listaPracticas = practicaDao.getPracticas();
    Practicas practicas = new Practicas();
    practicas.setPracticas(listaPracticas);
    return practicas;
}

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Practicas getPracticasUsuario(@QueryParam("idUsuario") int idUsuario) {
    List<Practica> listaPracticas = practicaDao.getPracticasByUser(idUsuario);
    Practicas practicas = new Practicas();
    practicas.setPracticas(listaPracticas);
    return practicas;
}
```

throw following exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by @Consumes and @Produces annotations at Java methods public com.sporty.model.Practicas com.sporty.resource.PracticasResource.getPracticas() and public com.sporty.model.Practicas com.sporty.resource.PracticasResource.getPracticasUsuario(int) at matching regular expression /practicas. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@1cc465f']
```

Is solution add another level on URI like /workouts/search?user=userId?

Is a problem derived from a poor URI design?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Practicas getPracticasUsuario(@QueryParam("idUsuario") Integer idUsuario) {
    final List<Practica> listaPracticas;
    if (idUsario != null) {
        practicaDao.getPracticasByUser(idUsuario);
    } else {
        practicaDao.getPracticas();
    }
    Practicas practicas = new Practicas();
    practicas.setPracticas(listaPracticas);
    return practicas;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Stein, I was thinking about that. But what happens if you have n different posibilities to filter collection? <br/> <pre> <code>(@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Practicas getPracticasUsuario(@QueryParam("param1") Integer param1, @QueryParam("param2") String param2) {
    final List<Practica> listaPracticas;
    if (param1 != null || param2 != null) {
        practicaDao.getPracticasFiltered(param1, param2);
    } else {
        practicaDao.getPracticas();
    }
...</code>

Comment: If N is small, you can just list them all out. If N is large, have one query parameter called filter. For instance, you could do ?filter=idUsario:es5f;nombre:Eric .. or any format you like. If N is very large or the filter parameters are large, you're going to need to do a POST to push the data up - there's a limit on the size of a request, usually around 8KB.

Comment: On the server side, you can throw all the filter params into a map and pass the map into getPracticasFiltered(). In that case, let an empty map mean no filters and you can save the special case call to getPracticas() if there are none.

Comment: query parameter called filter about you talk should be a @MatrixParam?

Comment: You could use a matrix, I suppose. I was thinking more of a normal query parameter that you do post-processing on to decode.